# Return tinyMCE editor to non-edit mode programmatically on save event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using the TinyMCE editor in the inline mode so that when the text is clicked on the editor comes up. I use the event "save_onsavecallback" event to save my changes via a Jquery Ajax call.

When I get confirmation of the post via AJAX I want to return the editor to it's pre-edit state (i.e. hide the menus). What is the tinyMCE method to do this?

I've read the documentation but nothing jumps out.